# Global Layout listeners returns 0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hello I want to get a relative layout's height and width with global layout listener:

```
final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = binding.rl;

      relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
              .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
           @Override
           public void onGlobalLayout() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                   width = relativeLayout.getWidth();
                   height = relativeLayout.getHeight();
                   relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                           .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

           }
       });
```

problem with my code is width and height are coming zero. Can somebody tell me any solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

```
   <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rl"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp12">

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other option try to use getMeasuredWidth() or getMeasuredHeight() :

```
relativeLayout.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int width = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
```

But according to your problem try to removeOnGlobalLayoutListener only when height or weight above 0, because if your layout width/height is "wrap_content" it can be really 0 :

```
    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    width = relativeLayout.getWidth();
                    height = relativeLayout.getHeight();

                    if (width > 0) {
                        relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: After doing this also my problem is same :

` relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                  .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
               @Override
               public void onGlobalLayout() {
                     setWidth(relativeLayout.getWidth());;
                     setHeight(relativeLayout.getHeight());;
                       if(getWidth()>0){
                           relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                                   .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                       } }
           });
`